Volatile struct member assignment: side effects / undefined behavior
I am considering the following code:
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct {
   uint32_t a;
} foo_t;

volatile foo_t foo;
volatile uint32_t b;

int main(void)
{
    foo.a = b;
    return 0;
}

In this sample code, the PC-Lint Plus will complain about the assignment with 931 diagnostic message:

Note 931: both sides have side effects
Indicates when both sides of an expression have side-effects. An example is n++ + f(). This is normally benign. The really troublesome cases such as n++ + n are caught via Warning 564.
Supports CERT C EXP10-C - Do not depend on the order of evaluation of subexpressions or the order in which side effects
take place.
Supports MISRA C 2012 Rule 1.3
Supports MISRA C 2004 Rule 1.2

Despite I am aware about side effects and sequence points , I cannot understand why this assignment triggers the message.
I see there are two side effects (write foo.a, read b), but they are related with different objects, so there is no undefined behavior according to https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/eval_order (emphasize by me):


If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to another side effect on the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined.
If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined.


Additionally:
If b is non-volatile, there is no warning.
If only the struct member is volatile (not whole struct), there is no warning.
Is such an assignment really risky for some reason from a C99 standard point of view?
